# Como traduzir "domain-specific language"?

Tags: português-brasileiro, tradução-inglês, tradução

Especificamente no contexto de desenvolvimento de software, existe uma classe de linguagens de programação chamada de *domain-specific languages*, que são pequenos dialetos que podem ser utilizados dentro de uma linguagem, ou uma linguagem completamente diferente mas focada em uma tarefa específica

(assim como em linguagens naturais temos o dialeto jurídico "legalês" e outros tipos de jargão, a *domain-specific language* é uma sublinguagem usada em para tarefas específicas)

Alguns exemplos em inglês:

> The GML scripting language used by GameMaker Studio is a domain-specific language targeted at novice programmers to easily be able to learn programming.
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language#GameMaker_Language)

> [...] The most obvious benefit of using [domain-specific languages] is that, once you've got a language and a transformation engine, your work in the particular aspect of software development covered by the [domain-specific language] becomes much more efficient, simply because you don't have to do the grunt work manually. [...]
>
> [Documentação do JetBrains MPS](https://www.jetbrains.com/mps/concepts/domain-specific-languages/) (siglas expandidas)

O Google Tradutor diz, e a [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/visualstudio/modeling/modeling-sdk-for-visual-studio-domain-specific-languages) corrobora:

> idiomas específicos do domínio

Porém eu acho que *idiomas específicos **ao** domínio* ou ***de** domínio* seriam mais apropriados, quando não se referindo a um domínio específico. Mas acho essa tradução literal (tanto a da Microsoft quanto minha adaptação) meio não-natural, então gostaria de saber: existe um termo estabelecido em português?

Comment: Idealmente a tua pergunta incluiria um par de frases-exemplo. :)

Comment: Ah sim, vou adicioná-las! Bem lembrado

Comment: Nunca vi "programming language" sendo escrito como "idioma de programação", mas sim, como "linguagem de programação", mas pode ser um jargão que desconheço.

Comment: Sem saber o que é estabelecido na área, eu traduziria como "linguagem de domínio específico" ou "linguagem de domínio restrito" ou ainda, como parece ser no francês, "linguagem dedicada". De qualquer forma, o "do" no lugar de "de" também me parece muito inadequado.

Comment: A Wikipédia tem https://pt.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_de_dom%C3%ADnio_espec%C3%ADfico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente, o "do" no lugar de "de" também me parece muito inadequado se você quer se referir à classe e não a um domínio específico.

Buscando pelas expressões sugeridas na pergunta e similares, "**linguagem de domínio específico**", parece ser bem estabelecido, sendo usado em diversos trabalhos acadêmicos e em livros como [Introdução ao Varnish Cache](https://books.google.de/books?id=Yu7JDgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT50&ots=cKHEr3XUPk&dq=%22linguagem%20de%20dom%C3%ADnio%20espec%C3%ADfico%22&pg=PT50#v=onepage&q=%22linguagem%20de%20dom%C3%ADnio%20espec%C3%ADfico%22&f=false), de Thijs Feryn, além do [verbete correspondente](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categoria:Linguagens_de_dom%C3%ADnio_espec%C3%ADfico) da Wikipedia.

Porém "linguagem específica de domínio" também é encontrada com frequência, incluindo no [DSL: Linguagens Específicas de Domínio](https://www.amazon.com.br/dp/8540702126/ref=cm_sw_r_tw_dp_U_x_fAWYEb5DH2FGT), de Martin Fowler. Portanto ambas as traduções parecem ser aceitáveis - inclusive há fontes que alternam entre as duas.

Comment: Esperava que alguém com experiência na área pudesse responder mas, como demorou, contribuo com meu pitaco.